# Compiling assets for multiple environments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In my application i have created different environments other that development, like staging, qa_test and production. (all are like production but having different settings/configurations)

Now my question is that i want to compile the assets for staging, qa_test and production all together so each environment (Rails.env) will catch up with their assets.

P.S i am having dynamic (environment depended) code in assets files.